# How to check if a value is null in T-SQL in parametrized query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Let's imagine there is a table `Product` with columns `ProductId` (smallint), `Title` (nullable nvarchar(100)) and `Price` (money). A title **can** be `null`.

There is a query which must return the products matching a specific title and a specific price:

```
using (SqlCommand getProducts = new SqlCommand("select ProductId from Product where Title = @title and Price = @price", sqlConnection))
{
    getProducts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
    getProducts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
}
```

When executing the following code with `title` set to null (or probably also to an empty string), for SQL Server, the comparison will be:

```
[...] where Title = NULL and Price = 123
```

which will return an empty set, since the correct syntax is:

```
[...] where Title is NULL and Price = 123
```

I could change the query string according to the null check of the title, but it will be unmaintainable.

Is there a clean way to make the comparison work without making the query string different when `Title` is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[...] WHERE COALESCE(Title,'') = COALESCE(@Title,'') AND Price = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsNull() like this...

```
using (SqlCommand getProducts = new SqlCommand("select ProductId from Product where IsNull(Title, '') = IsNull(@title, '') and Price = @price", sqlConnection))
```

If the title is null, then an empty string will be used for the comparison rather than null.

[edit] Updated after a1ex07's comment below.

Comment: In the case where `@title` is null, wouldn't that still end up translating to `'' = NULL` for `Title` s that are null?

Comment: If `@title` is NULL, the result of `IsNull(Title, '') = @title` is also NULL(false). It will probably work if you add 1 more `ISNULL` : `IsNull(Title, '') = ISNULL(@title,'')`.